# for loop - move deeper on numeric key in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, nested

i've managed to parse an array out of my own language. (for this: called lance project language - lpl)

so.. \lance(says(hello))
will be formatted to

```
Array
(
    [0] => lpl_struct
        (
            [args] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => lpl_struct
                                (
                                    [args] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => lpl_struct
                                                        (
                                                            [args] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => hello
                                                                )
                                                            [funcname] => text
                                                        )
                                                )
                                        )
                                    [funcname] => says
                                )
                        )
                )
            [funcname] => lance
        )
)
```

im now trying to create an xml struct out of this, here is my attempt to do so:

```
    function arr2xml($array) {
    $xml = '';

    if (is_array($array) || is_object($array)) {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if (is_numeric($key)) {
                #move deeper in array to get the right NON-NUMERIC key
            }

            $xml .= '<' . $key . '>' . "\n" . $this->arr2xml($value) . '</' . $key . '>' . "\n";
        }
    } else {
        $xml = htmlspecialchars($array, ENT_QUOTES) . "\n";
    }

    return $xml;
}
```

what i'm getting out of it so far is:

```
<0>
    <args>
        <0>
            <0>
                <args>
                    <0>
                        <0>
                            <args>
                                <0>
                                hello
                                </0>
                            </args>
                            <funcname>
                            text
                            </funcname>
                        </0>
                    </0>
                </args>
                <funcname>
                says
                </funcname>
            </0>
        </0>
    </args>
    <funcname>
    lance
    </funcname>
</0>
```

is it possible to "skip" the numeric keys in the array?. say to.. move deeper to the next "real" array key?

our should i rethink my created array

thanks for any answer.

sry for bad formatting. im kinda new to stackoverflow.
lance

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you implemented the code block under `if (is_numeric($key)) {}`?  Otherwise, I think it's normal you end up with the `<0>` since you're still building a tag when the key is numeric.

Comment: not yet. i'm not quite sure how to peek deeper into the array and skip the <0>. tried "next(array)" which gives me the next <0>/<1>.(works right, but it's not what i meant to do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to rebuild your array using the following:

```
$arr = array();
$arr[] = array(
    'args'=>array(
        array(
            'args'=>array(
                array(
                    'args'=>array(
                        'hello',
                    ),
                    'funcname'=>'text',
                ),
            ),
            'funcname'=>'says',
        ),
    ),
    'funcname'=>'lance',
);
```

I then updated your arr2xml function:

```
function arr2xml($array) {
    $xml = '';

    if (is_array($array) || is_object($array)) {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if (is_numeric($key)) {
                // Skip a numeric key and recurse.
                $xml .= arr2xml($value);
            }
            else {
                $xml .= '<' . $key . '>' . "\n" . arr2xml($value) . '</' . $key . '>' . "\n";
            }
        }
    } else {
        $xml = htmlspecialchars($array, ENT_QUOTES) . "\n";
    }

    return $xml;
}
```

This produced the following, which is close to what you're looking for:

```
<args>
    <args>
        <args>
            hello
        </args>
        <funcname>
            text
        </funcname>
    </args>
    <funcname>
        says
    </funcname>
</args>
<funcname>
    lance
</funcname>
```

The only thing missing is the root  element.  You can add that manually using:

```
'<xml>' . arr2xml($arr) . '</xml>'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: does your array above indeed have no numeric keys or did you just forgot to post them? if not, it misses the whole point of going to the next dimension of array if key is numeric. don't get me wrong. i know i could change the "input array", but i'm still curious if this is possible somehow.

Comment: If I removed the recursion I added and also remove the else of the is_numeric, this is what I get:
`<0>
 <args>
  <0>
   <args>
    <0>
     <args>
      <0>
       hello
      </0>
     </args>
     <funcname>
      text
     </funcname>
    </0>
   </args>
   <funcname>
    says
   </funcname>
  </0>
 </args>
 <funcname>
  lance
 </funcname>
</0>`
So to answer your question, it has them.

Comment: didn't had time to test, just read and was wondering. sry for that.
it works fine. thank you!

Comment: Awesome!  If you wouldn't mind marking this as the correct answer, that'd be great!

Comment: sure. as soon as i found out how O:

may i ask you some more questions about this loop? via pn maybe

Comment: Sure.  Not certain what PN is though.

Comment: pn = pm* like private message. as it turns out my reputation is too low to start a chat